# What does ./error_prone.sh >>~/stdout.txt 2>>~/stderr.txt do?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stderr

This is the contents of error_prone.sh

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

 n=$(( RANDOM % 100 ))

 if [[ n -eq 42 ]]; then
    echo "Something went wrong"
    >&2 echo "The error was using magic numbers"
    exit 1
 fi

 echo "Everything went according to plan"
```

I'm trying to understand this line of code,  ./error_prone.sh >>~/stdout.txt 2>>~/stderr.txt from another file, that's supposed to append the error logs and error output from error_prone.sh onto txt files. I understand that ./error_prone.sh >>~/stdout.txt wires the output of error_prone.sh into stdout.txt, but don't understand how it relates to 2>>~/stderr.txt. How come 2>>~/stderr.txt can't be on a separate line, since 2 is the file descriptor for errors so it seems like directly appending the error logs into stderror.txt seems like it'll work? I can see it's something related to the stream, but don't really understand completely.

I tried my best trying to understand this, but am still having trouble.

Comment: "*How come 2>>~/stderr.txt can't be on a separate line*". Why do you think it needs to be on a seperate line? That does exactly what you said it does - it redirects stderr from the program into that file. If it were on a seperate line then it would be a different command and would not be connected to running that script.

Comment: 2>>~/stderr.txt on a new line would not have a command from which to redirect stderr.  `error_prone.sh 2>>~/stderr.txt`  -- this is capturing the stderr form the script and redirecting it to stderr.txt (and not the terminal).